# Body is infront of all elements rendering all unclickable

Tags: html, css

This is probably really dumb but my body is covering all my elements rendering everything unclickable...I fixed this before but I forgot how.

https://codepen.io/Tehan123/pen/VgdRBQ

```
`<body>
  <section class="Body-Wrapper">
  <div class="Page-Wrapper-First">


          <img class="logo" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/776/776541.png"</img>

    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Features </a> </li>
       <li><a href="#">How It Works </a> </li>
       <li><a href="#">Pricing </a> </li>
       </ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="menu" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149176.svg"> </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">How It Works</a>
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>

    </nav>
      <section class="hero">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1> Creates 'a place beyond time' for its guests.</h1>
        </div>
      <img class="hero-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1320686/pexels-photo-1320686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"</img>
      </section>
    </div>
   </section>
    </body
```

>
    `

Answer (score 4):

You have a negative `z-index` on your body. Whenever elements have a negative z-index they're not clickable and everything as a child of body will be the same. You need to set a value greater than 0.

This is the last 3 lines of your CSS

```
body {
  z-index: -3;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also it seems like you have a `z-index: -2` on `.Body-Wrapper`. You should use a value greater than `0`.

When you remove/change these two values it might look like your page is broken, it's because you have a bunch of negative z-index value in other places. You need to change those to positive as well.

Comment: There is also a negative z-index on the .Body-Wrapper element this needs to be 0 too.

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I'd removed the body one previously and was so confused about why it was still broken.

Removing both negative z-indexes fixed it. Thank you!